# Org Agenda. Any support for locations?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I'd like to schedule events in a conference with the respective room numbers.

Basically, instead of:

```
SCHEDULED: <2017-04-24 Mon 13:45>
```

I'd have

```
SCHEDULED: <2017-04-24 Mon 13:45 Room ABC>
```

What is the best way to do that, i.e., include locations? Should I use a custom property?

Comment: Scheduling, deadlines, and timestamps are for time information, not location.  Either put something in the [property](http://orgmode.org/guide/Properties.html) drawer, or use a [tag](http://orgmode.org/manual/Tags.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `LOCATION` property, which is one of the default properties.  Set the property with `C-c C-x p location`.

You might also want to see the location in the agenda.  There are several ways to accomplish this.  The easiest is [column view](http://orgmode.org/manual/Column-view.html#Column-view).  Set `org-column-default-format` (or the `COLUMNS` property to contain `LOCATION`.  For example add:

```
#+COLUMNS: %25ITEM %TODO %3PRIORITY %TAGS %LOCATION
```

to the top of your org file.  Activate column view using `C-c C-x C-c` in the agenda view or your org file.